# Early morning parking enforcement without signage in California

Tags: california, parking, local-authorities

I recently moved to Glendora, CA which has an [early morning parking prohibition](http://qcode.us/codes/glendora/view.php?topic=10-10_12-10_12_020&frames=on). I was unaware of this until I got a ticket.

Where I got the ticket is a typical suburban street, no posted signs or curb markings indicate this is a restricted parking area.

I saw [CA 22500.2(b)](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=22500.2.) which requires signs for local authorities to "post signs that delineate the area specified".

Since the area is not clearly marked, can this ticket be enforced? Are there any CA laws specifying how close the posted signs need to be to the parking area?

Comment: Looks like https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=22507.5.&lawCode=VEH is the applicable statue. 22500 is for emergency vehicles.

Comment: Note that 22507.5 contains no requirement for signage.  Compare to [22507.6](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=22507.6.&lawCode=VEH) which does.